# ActionEvent - Changing JLabel on button press

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, awt, actionevent

I'm still new to Java and I'm having trouble with changing the image in a JLabel when a button has been clicked. I don't get any compiler errors but I do get a run time error.

```
Line 107: l1.setIcon(icon);
```

"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
public class HomeController1 extends JPanel  implements ActionListener  
{
private int choice;
private JButton add;
private JLabel l1; 

public HomeController1() {

    // Create panels and set layouts
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4)); 
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel (new GridLayout(3,3));
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    // Create buttons
    add = new JButton("ADD APPLIANCE");

    //Add ActionListeners
    add.addActionListener(this);

    // Add buttons to panel
    p1.add(add);

    // Default ImageIcon
    ImageIcon blank =  new ImageIcon("blank.jpg");

    // Create Jlabels to hold blank image
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel(blank);

    // Add JLabels to Panel
    p2.add(l1);

    //Add contents to Frame
    p3.add(p1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    p3.add(p2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p3);

}       

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == add)
        {
          choice = 0;

           if (choice == 0)
           {
                Clock clock1 = new Clock();
                ImageIcon icon = clock1.getPicture();
                l1.setIcon(icon);
           }
        }
    }
```

}

Full Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at HomeController.actionPerformed(HomeController.java:107)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Copy/paste the entire stacktrace (that includes line numbers) as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15926319/edit).

Comment: `Clock clock1 = new Clock();`  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Likely that `clock1.getPicture()` is returning null.

Comment: All such java errors come with a stacktrace.  The stacktrace *tells you the line of code that has a null pointer*.  If you really can't figure it out from there, post the stacktrace.  In addition, when posting problems with which you want help, *post the conditions under which your error occurs*.  Is it when the program starts?  When the button is clicked?  Only on alternate Thursdays?  Assume your volunteer helpers have never seen your program or your error message, and would like enough information to be able to help you.

Comment: @BlackBox its telling me that the null pointer is being returned on line 107 " l1.setIcon(icon); " ?

Comment: *`Line 107`*  The source you posted does not have imports *or* 117 lines.  ***For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).***

Comment: Yes, `clock1.getPicture()` will be returning null, and you're trying to use a null object here: `l1.setIcon(icon);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem comes from the fact that you have declared a global variable in home controller:

```
private JLabel l1;
```

and another one, local, in your constructor:

```
// Create Jlabels to hold blank image
JLabel l1 = new JLabel(blank);
```

In your constructor, you defined a variable with the same name as in your class, but it's a different variable. The one in your constructor hides the one in your class.
So, in the end, only your constructor variable is initialized. If you change your code like this in your constructor,

```
// Create Jlabels to hold blank image
l1 = new JLabel(blank);
```

Then you'll only have one global variable in your class and you won't get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thank you, Its always the simple mistakes that catch you out.